# Acer Aspire 5734Z

Tags: acer

I have an Acer Aspire 5734Z, 3.00 GB, 64 bit O.S. I want to know if there's a distro that's absolutely lighting fast for this computer. I have tried Ubuntu 14.04 on my old Dell Inspirion and it was the fastest thing I had ever seen (since moving away from snail slow windows). I was considering the new Ubuntu Studio 15.04 for the Acer I have. Do you guys think that it would be too "heavy" and slow down this older computer?

Answer (score 0):

No it's not heavy at all. Especially with that much ram. Ubuntustudio is one of the lightest running desktops. The extras are installed software for media that do not run in the background.

Ubuntustudio actually runs really well even on old hardware as it uses the xfce desktop. I've ran Ubuntustudio on old XP and Vista computers and they ran nice whereas Gnome Shell and Unity on the same boxes would lag.